# PHP Force Download Header failed on Mobile Devices

Tags: php, android, codeigniter, curl

Helo, i have code like this to force download a file from another server via URL (remote).

```
  $file_size = get_headers($url,TRUE);

  header('Pragma: public'); // required
  header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
  header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: accept, authorization');
  header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, HEAD');
  header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
  header('Content-Type: audio/mpeg');
  header("Content-Disposition:  attachment; filename=\"myfile.ogg\";" );
  //header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
  header('X-Cache: HIT');
  header('Content-Length: '.$file_size['Content-Length']);
  readfile($url);
```

This PHP code works well on PC Browser (I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 with Google Chrome Browser). Also works on wget, and download via curl.

But, when i'm download from my phone (Android CyanogenMod ROM 4.4.4 with google chrome browser and UC web browser) it always say unsuccessfull while downloading ( ex: when progressbar reach 30%, download failed).

I'm using codeigniter to create entire this web, when i'm try to check the header, and this is the result.

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 20 Mar 2015 01:08:13 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.6
Set-Cookie: lagu_session=a%3A5%3A%7Bs%3A10%3A%22session_id%22%3Bs%3A32%3A%22c0bf700656a88ff98ddce8098c7ea1e3%22%3Bs%3A10%3A%22ip_address%22%3Bs%3A9%3A%22127.0.0.1%22%3Bs%3A10%3A%22user_agent%22%3Bs%3A11%3A%22curl%2F7.35.0%22%3Bs%3A13%3A%22last_activity%22%3Bi%3A1426813694%3Bs%3A9%3A%22user_data%22%3Bs%3A0%3A%22%22%3B%7D2c0017d813b89cb687b243a8a4c73771fe1c9083; expires=Fri, 20-Mar-2015 03:08:14 GMT; Max-Age=7200; path=/
Pragma: public
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: accept, authorization
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, HEAD
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="myfile.ogg";
X-Cache: HIT
Content-Length: 4017422
Content-Type: audio/mpeg
```

What is the problem, there are any idea?

that this line cause problem?

```
Set-Cookie: lagu_session=a%3A5%3A%7Bs%3A10%3A%22session_id%22%3Bs%3A32%3A%22c0bf700656a88ff98ddce8098c7ea1e3%22%3Bs%3A10%3A%22ip_address%22%3Bs%3A9%3A%22127.0.0.1%22%3Bs%3A10%3A%22user_agent%22%3Bs%3A11%3A%22curl%2F7.35.0%22%3Bs%3A13%3A%22last_activity%22%3Bi%3A1426813694%3Bs%3A9%3A%22user_data%22%3Bs%3A0%3A%22%22%3B%7D2c0017d813b89cb687b243a8a4c73771fe1c9083; expires=Fri, 20-Mar-2015 03:08:14 GMT; Max-Age=7200; path=/
```

FYI: When my friends download using their phone , it's no error. This problem on my phone? I'm trying to download some file from another website, and it's no problem with my phone.

Thanks for any suggestion and solution :D

**EDIT:** 
I think it's server issue, i'm using openshift (free plan)  and get that issue. Now i'm move my web app to DigitalOcean and it's works well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I found the problem, there is no about the server. Here is my code snippet

```
//check if http_range is sent by browser (or download manager)
if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE']))
{
    list($size_unit, $range_orig) = explode('=', $_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE'], 2);
    if ($size_unit == 'bytes')
    {
        //multiple ranges could be specified at the same time, but for simplicity only serve the first range
        //http://tools.ietf.org/id/draft-ietf-http-range-retrieval-00.txt
        list($range, $extra_ranges) = explode(',', $range_orig, 2);
    }
    else
    {
        $range = '';
        header('HTTP/1.1 416 Requested Range Not Satisfiable');
        exit;
    }
}
else
{
    $range = '';
}

//figure out download piece from range (if set)
list($seek_start, $seek_end) = explode('-', $range, 2);

//set start and end based on range (if set), else set defaults
//also check for invalid ranges.
$seek_end   = (empty($seek_end)) ? ($header_content_size - 1) : min(abs(intval($seek_end)),($header_content_size - 1));
$seek_start = (empty($seek_start) || $seek_end < abs(intval($seek_start))) ? 0 : max(abs(intval($seek_start)),0);

//Only send partial content header if downloading a piece of the file (IE workaround)
if ($seek_start > 0 || $seek_end < ($header_content_size - 1))
{
    header('HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content');
    header('Content-Range: bytes '.$seek_start.'-'.$seek_end.'/'.$header_content_size);
    header('Content-Length: '.($seek_end - $seek_start + 1));
}else{
header("Content-Length: $header_content_size");
}

header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
@set_time_limit(0);

fseek($file, $seek_start);

while(!feof($file))
{
    print(@fread($file, 1024*8));
    ob_flush();
    flush();
    if (connection_status()!=0)
    {
        @fclose($file);
        exit;
    }
}

// file save was a success
@fclose($file);
exit;
```

And now, my download script is support for resummable download.

Comment: how about failed download because perms denied or file doest exist,